# Setup a Google Ads BigQuery Transfer but shows empty tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I've setup a Google BigQuery Transfer to transfer Google Ads (formerly AdWords) data. The transfer job is successful and shows no error.

> Summary: succeeded 87 jobs, failed 0 jobs.

However, I went over to the Datasets and saw a lot of views and partitioned tables. But none has any data.

I've read through all the documentation on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer#migrating_google_ads_data_to_mccs, but couldn't figure out where went wrong.

Anyone has similar issue?

Comment: - Have you verified that the data actually exists in Ads?
- How are you checking your tables for the existence of this data?
- Could you provide more context about the issue? The link that you've shared talks about backfills and migrating existing Google Ads data in BigQuery Data Transfer Service to the MCC structure. Which specific steps have you followed? Have you been able to successfully migrate Ads data to BQ before?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried connecting the Google BigQuery Transfer to another Google Ads account and it works. I could see data size and I could query data. I suspect that the initial account I connected are for Google Hotel Ads, which probably wasn't supported.